# Exclude record if last 3 characters is some string, only if the fourth characters from the last is a specific characters

Tags: mysql

I want to exclude data if the last 3 characters is "abc, **but only if** the fourth char is not "." (dot).

For example, "sdgabc" is **excluded**, but "sdg.abc" is **included**.

How can I achieve this?

`RIGHT(column_name, 3) <> "abc"` doesn't work because "sdg.abc" also filtered out.

Comment: try this `SELECT * FROM table WHERE RIGHT(column_name, 3) <> "abc" AND RIGHT(column_name, 4) <> ".abc";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a combination of `LIKE` here:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE column_name NOT LIKE '%abc' OR  -- doesn't end in 'abc'
      column_name LIKE '%.abc';       -- unless it ends in '.abc'
```